# Firebase android not working outside testing devices

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this new app and have added Firebase Firestore and Cloud Firestore.
User can sign up with email and pass, and log in successfully.
Then user can enter birthday in myprofile and update the info.

The problem is this, it works fine in Emulator. It works fine in testing device. But when I release the app and download it with another android phone, it stops working.
I have picture of database for 2 different situations.

**First one:**

[image: 1]

I used real device and downloaded app from store to sign up a user: My `user1`

**Second one:**

[image: 2]

is a sign up from Emulator device same version. My `user2`

Problem when sign up is from a downloaded app:

```
a "aJ3vfJUiNFQXbQ394SHbGUlV7eu2"
b "My name"
c "5@6.com"
d ""
e ""
```

Correct one from Emulator:

```
birthday ""
email "7@8.com"
id "ldYDz3GAo6YOUNiIGZyMg3lwVXH3"
image ""
userName "My name 2"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops working"? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I mean in Emulator it would show user name, you could change name, birthday etc. but when I download the app from store and run it and log in, it changes and you can not do those functions.

Comment: I found the problem I think. toObject metod seems not to work correctly. I sent the data one by one as string and it works now. but any help would be great, because I know it's not the best solution.

Comment: Looks like it could be related to pro-guard which is renaming you variables to "a,b,c,d,e", try putting progueard rules to preserve the data class you are uploading to firebase

Answer (score 1):

When you make release builds for android typically proguard is used to obfuscate your code - this means renaming all your classes to things like A, B, C and all your variables to things like a, b, c, d, e. It looks like thats what could be happening here. You are uploading a data object like this:

```
data class PersonInfo(
    var birthday: String = "",
    var email: String = "",
    var id: String = "",
    var image: String = "",
    var userName: String = "" 
)
```

And proguard is obfuscating it to be something like:

```
data class A(
    var a: String = "",
    var b: String = "",
    var c: String = "",
    var d: String = "",
    var e: String = "" 
)
```

To tell proguard to not obfuscate a specific class you can add a rule in `proguard-rules.pro` (which should be located in you `/app/` folder) like this:

```
-keep class your.package.name.ClassName
```

This should preserve the original class and fix your issue (assuming the issue was from proguard as I suspect)

Comment: I just faced a problem after uploading the app to Google Play. As many suggested, the problem may be with the ProGuard configuration and I did exactly as in your post. I added `-keep class` for all my model classes (I think that's what I am supposed to do). What I have to do next since my app is already uploaded to Google Play? Thanks.